# Constructor Parameters Via Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, types, parameters, constructor

I am using Reflection in Java. Can I please have some help to get the constructor parameter names and values?

Here is my code:

```
  public String getConstructors(Class aClass)
  {
  StringBuilder ClassConstructors = new StringBuilder();
  Constructor[] Constructors = aClass.getConstructors();
  String separator = System.getProperty( "line.separator" );
  for (Constructor c: Constructors)
  {
      boolean isPublic = Modifier.isPublic(c.getModifiers());
      Class[] parameterTypes = c.getParameterTypes();
      for (Class pt : parameterTypes)
      {
          System.out.println(pt.getName());
          //Field[] Fields = pt.getDeclaredFields();
          //for (Field f : Fields) 
          //{
              //System.out.println(f.getType());
          //}
      }
  }
  return ClassConstructors.toString();
```

}

The constructor that I am testing has the following parameters:

```
String Name, int Diameter
```

The `System.out.println(pt.getName());` line of code is currently printing out the following:

```
java.lang.String
int
```

Is it possible to get the Type and Name of each of the parameters?

Comment: Java bytecode doesn't contain names of args

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already have the types, and there's no way to get the names (since they're not preserved as part of the bytecodes).

Comment: Is this the same for methods? Method names cannot be retrieved?

Comment: @user2023359: Method names -- yes. Argument names -- no.

Answer (score 1):

Name is not available via reflection in JAVA.